Sending personal items back home to the UK whilst travelling Asia?
I am currently on a 4 month vacation in Asia with a backpack filled with stuff for specific things.
The problem is some of the stuff I have with me is no longer needed (warm clothing, hiking gear) as I am traveling to Southeast Asia after doing the colder northern parts of Japan and China etc.
This is good quality things that I bought in the UK years and years ago. The problem is I think I might still need to pay import tax/duty on them.
Looking at the rules on here - https://www.gov.uk/goods-sent-from-abroad/tax-and-duty
It looks like I would have to pay VAT on them, but the thing is. I have already paid VAT on them.
Any advice, do I print off receipts from Amazon and eBay and include it in the parcel home with a letter saying "Hello Taxman, don't charge me on these things as I already paid VAT on them"
I could just keep the stuff on me to save the hassle but it would add about 6-7kgs of weight to my backpack.
Anyone had a similar situation, any advice how to get this stuff sent home?
Items:

Hiking trousers (£90)
Hiking socks (a bit smelly)
Undergarment
Hoodie (I got free at a festival, but has sentimental value)
Box of Gopro accessories (I am keeping the Gopro on me)
Hiking poles (they're cheap but seems wasteful to bin them here)
Beanie hat

I mean it is definitely worth more than the limit to send home, so its a bit of a dilemma.
Any advice recommended!

Why do you think you might have to pay import tax or duty on these items you'd bought in the UK in years past? Whoever imported them into the UK back then would have paid the tax or duty on those items.

Not sure, but reading the guidance on the Gov.uk site it seems like I would have to pay for it, if I shipped things back.

Customs collects tax and duty on items obtained overseas, and brought into the UK for the first time to stay, not on everything in the traveler's possession.

Tax collection is the default. Probably someone should check on website (or contact them), on how to declare your stuff as own property with taxes already paid in UK. It is important to have correct marking, else you must pay tax, and reclaim for refund (but paying processing fee, etc.). -- returns and repairs are similar cases where you should not pay taxes the second time.

@DavidRecallsMonica That is not correct. There are simplified processes for items and personal luggage carried by travellers when crossing a border, but these simplifications do not apply to items which are shipped or mailed by post. Import tax excemptions are not so easy and a purchase receipt will usually not suffice. A purchase receipt for e.g. a jacket does not prove that you have bought the jacket you are sending by mail.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo I certainly agree that the procedures for claiming exemption from import duty vary depending upon whether the item is shipped or carried. My point was only that duty is not assessed by a country on items previously imported into the country and for which duty has already been paid. How the traveler gets to that end can be a challenge.
